# Graph model with 1 numerical and 2 categorical variable

Tags: r, graph, glm

I can't seem to find the appropriate code to plot this model:

```
model <- glm( Inter ~ Temp + Period + Vis.Level, data=mydata)
```

'Inter' is a behaviour called Interaction and is measured in minutes. The data is as follows:

```
Inter Vis.Level    Period Temp
0.0       Low   Morning   17
0.0       Low   Morning   17
0.0       Low   Morning   16
3.0       Low Afternoon   17
3.0       Low Afternoon   16
4.5       Low Afternoon   15
0.0      High   Morning   10
0.0      High   Morning   18
0.0      High   Morning   15
0.0      High Afternoon   17
1.5      High Afternoon   17
0.0      High Afternoon   21
```

I would like the graph to look like this

[image]

Not sure if this is possible but any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is actually pretty easy. Have you perused some tutorials, e.g., introductions to the ggplot2 package?

Comment: Have a look at `?predict.lm` if you want to do this manually

Comment: @Roland I am actually reading about ggplot now... I can find similar examples, but whenever I change the script to fit my data it won't plot! I'll keep reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="Inter Vis.Level    Period Temp
0.0       Low   Morning   17
0.0       Low   Morning   17
0.0       Low   Morning   16
3.0       Low Afternoon   17
3.0       Low Afternoon   16
4.5       Low Afternoon   15
0.0      High   Morning   10
0.0      High   Morning   18
0.0      High   Morning   15
0.0      High Afternoon   17
1.5      High Afternoon   17
0.0      High Afternoon   21", header=TRUE)

#fit your model
fit <- lm(Inter ~ Temp + Period + Vis.Level, data=DF)
#create new data for prediction
DFpredict <- expand.grid(Vis.Level = unique(DF$Vis.Level), 
                         Period = unique(DF$Period),
                         Temp = c(min(DF$Temp), max(DF$Temp)))
#predict
DFpredict$Inter <- predict(fit, newdata=DFpredict)

#plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x=Temp, y=Inter, 
               colour=Vis.Level, shape=Period, linetype=Period)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=DFpredict)
```

[image: resulting plot]